# What happens to Tien after the episode - "Tien goes all out"?

Tags: dragon-ball

In the anime TV series of Dragonball Z, what happens to Tien after the attack he does on Nappa? He hasn't been shown after that. Does he die in his attempt to give all his energy into that attack?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Taken from the [wiki](http://dragonball.wikia.com/wiki/Tien_Shinhan).

It's just above the "Biography" part. There is also a more descriptive part about it in the "Biography" part.

> During Dragon Ball Z, he is seen striving to become a powerful warrior, and still hopes to surpass Goku one day. He valiantly fights and defeats a Saibaman when the Saiyans arrive, and does battle with Nappa, during which Chiaotzu sacrifices himself in vain, causing Tien to put all his effort into one final attack, which fails. Tien dies a hero's death, but is revived later by Porunga. When the conflict with the Androids comes into full swing, Tien puts his life on the line numerous times when assisting his friends against the mechanical demons, most notably when using his life-force to hold Semi-Perfect Cell at bay, nearly sacrificing his own life to allow Android 16 and Android 18 to escape, thus saving the Earth from certain destruction. After the defeat of Cell, Tien goes off to continue his training. When Super Buu threatens Earth's existence seven years later, he arrives just in time to save Gohan from certain death. However, he is knocked out when Buu's severed legs reanimate and kick him, and later perishes when the Earth is destroyed.